# Why does re.VERBOSE prevent my regex pattern from working?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, svn

I want to use the following regex to get modified files from svn log, it works fine as a single line, but since it's complex, I want to use `re.VERBOSE` so that I can add comment to it, then it stopped working. What am I missing here? Thanks!

```
revision='''r123456 | user | 2013-12-22 11:21:41 -0700 (Thu, 22 Dec 2013) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/abc/python/test/module
   A /trunk/abc/python/test/module/__init__.py
   A /trunk/abc/python/test/module/usage.py
   A /trunk/abc/python/test/module/logger.py

copied from test
'''

import re

# doesn't work
print re.search('''
            (?<=Changed\spaths:\n)  
            ((\s{3}[A|M|D]\s.*\n)*)
            [(?=\n)|]       
            ''', revision, re.VERBOSE).groups()

# works
print re.search('(?<=Changed\spaths:\n)((\s{3}[A|M|D]\s.*\n)*)[(?=\n)|]', revision).groups()[0]
```

The string I want to extract is:

```
   A /trunk/abc/python/test/module
   A /trunk/abc/python/test/module/__init__.py
   A /trunk/abc/python/test/module/usage.py
   A /trunk/abc/python/test/module/logger.py
```

Comment: How do you think that `\n` is being treated? This is one of the reasons you're supposed to use raw strings for regexes.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/xlYIMF. The main issue is that you have to pass it as a raw string literal. Note you corrupted the lookahead by enclosing it with `[...]` (it became a character class part).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a raw string literal:

```
re.search(r'''
            (?<=Changed\spaths:\n)  
            (?:\s{3}[AMD]\s.*\n)*
            (?=\n)    
            ''', revision, re.VERBOSE)
```

See this fixed [Python demo](http://ideone.com/xlYIMF).

The main issue is that you have to pass it as a raw string literal, or use `\\n` instead of `\n`. Otherwise, `\n` (being a literal newline) is ignored inside the regex pattern, is treated as formatting whitespace (read more about that in the [Python `re` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE)).

Also, note you corrupted the lookahead by enclosing it with `[...]` (it became a character class part) and the `|` inside character classes are treated as literal pipes (thus, here, they should be removed).

Comment: I've just learned this :) What would happen if one group doesn't match? will it all fall apart or only those who match return?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR There is a match, or there is no match. You can only access groups of a successful match.